# Convert user passwords to MD5?

Tags: database, users, password

I am in the process of migrating my site out of Wordpress and I need to filter the registration and/or login process so there is a separate database field that holds the user password in a hash that can be easily used on a non-WP site.

How can I go about this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Passwords are stored in the database *already hashed*, so where are you accessing the cleartext passwords?

Comment: I'm not viewing them in cleartext. I just need new users to have MD5 at least. I figured having two columns for passwords for the Wordpress hash + a column for MD5 that gets updated as people login / new people register.

Comment: I'm sorry; I still don't understand your question. Where do these "two columns" exist? Are you writing some sort of export script or something?

Comment: So, are you asking how to take an SHA-hashed password, and convert it into an MD5-hashed password? If so, that question really isn't **WordPress** related.

Comment: The user_pass in the wp_users table is the hashed WP password field. Since I can't just convert those to MD5 or anything, I thought if I created a separate field in the wp_users table called user_pass_md5, I could update that whenever a new person registers, or when a person logs in (so it checks the user_pass value, if they authenticate with it, then store an md5 version of their password in the user_pass_md5).

Comment: I'm not really asking about converting hashed passwords. I'm asking for solutions on how I can migrate Wordpress.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why MD5? MD5 isn't exactly secure these days, it's a well studied subject complete with rainbow tables and algoriths. Hand me your list of unsalted MD5 hashes and I'll get you the originals within a few hours, salted MD5s will take a while longer.

Comment: It really doesn't have to be MD5. SHA works as well. It just needs to be something I can use on a non-Wordpress site.

Comment: If your reasoning is to enforce security, then simply changing the hashing algorithm won't help very much, if at all. But combining that hash with a salt will help... @Tom: How much longer will take you to get me the salted MD5s? 10 years? 20? :)

Comment: So, you might want to re-format your question to focus on **how to filter the registration and/or login process, to add a separate DB field to hold the user password with a non-SHA hash**; otherwise, I don't think the question is really in-scope.

Comment: @OneTrickPony that depends if you've given me the salt or if I have to acquire it by nefarious means

Comment: If you're looking for a hashing scheme, I would advise you read this blogpost first http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to write code to grab the user's password on login and write it out in a different format to a different location. Over time, you would thus accumulate the passwords in a different format than WordPress itself uses (it makes use of the excellent [PHPass library](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) for password storage).

To do this, you'd most likely use the "check_password" filter, which can receive the boolean result of the password check, the plaintext password, the hashed password (using PHPass), and the user ID number.

However, before doing this, you should probably consider a better approach. Storing passwords in a less secure manner such as MD5 isn't really advisable. If you need to authenticate in another web application, just use the existing hashes and the PHPass library to do the authentication against them. It's pretty much as simple as this:

```
require_once( '/wp-includes/class-phpass.php');
$hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
$check = $hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hash);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because hashing is a one way procedure, to convert to MD5 you have 2 choices:

- Ask users to reset their passwords when you transition to the new system
- Bruteforce the existing WordPress hashes. This will likely take many years at great expense.

I advise you opt for the first option. It allows you to let users choose more secure passwords at the same time or enforce stricter/better/longer password rules. Storing both hashes would be a bad idea ( and a potential security issue )

Also I would advise against using MD5 as vanilla MD5 can be bruteforced with relative ease nowadays using rainbow tables. SHA-2 is a better bet, coupled with salts based on the user themselves, e.g. `sha_hash_password(username.'_'.password.'_'.common_salt);`

Comment: I'm currently converting a non-WordPress site with forum to a Wordpress driven site, and we chose the first option for managing the user transition.  We are pushing the user list into WordPress then running a mass password reset, sending everyone their new randomly generated passwords.  This has an added bonus of notifying everyone there is a new site launch, potentially bringing them back to the site/forums.